# call other layout and block in custom phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, template

i want to call other layout and block in my phtml

Block Name:-**catalog/product_view**

Layout handle:-**catalog_product_view**

i have used below code but it's not working.

**Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view');**

Can any one help me on this problem ?

Any references or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: What  is ur exact acquirement?

Comment: i want to print $this->getTierPriceHtml() in my template, for $this  i want to call that layout and block. @AmitBera

Comment: on which page ?

Comment: on my custom template.@AmitBera

Answer (score 1):

1) **On phtml files**

`$this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('template path')->toHtml(); // change the block type as per your need and change the template path as well.`

2) **From layout xml**

```
<your_handler>
    <block type="your block" name="name">
     <block type="core/template" name="name here" as="alias here" template="path/here/test.phtml"/>
    </block>
   </your_handler>
```

Now call the file inside your block. you can call like this `$this->getChildHtml(alias name)`;

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

But you should be send few params

```
$productObject =Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('[ProductID]');
$block= Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view')
          ->setTierPriceTemplate('catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml')  
        ->getTierPriceHtml($productObject,$this); 

// gerenarate html

 echo $block->toHtml()
```

Also note:  product $productObject should be full product object

Comment: what is $productObject ?

Comment: means object of product :D . Object of this class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` . +1 from me.

Comment: yes, need to send product object

Comment: I can only pass the product id or name can you please explain little more.i am beginner in magento.

Comment: No, you cannot product id .. need to send product means `$productObject =Mage::getModel(''catalog/product')->load('productId')`;

Comment: $productObject =Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('13233'); 
$block =Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view')->getTierPriceHtml($productObject);
// gerenarate html
echo $block->toHtml();  but not woking

Comment: anwer update.. please checl